# Current Timestamp in Derived Column of Dataflow in Azure Data FActory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Inside my dataflow in Azure Data Factory, I want to have a derived column with current timestamp in Australian Eastern Standard Time (AEST) timezone (similar to getdate()) and use it as one of the columns to map in the sink.

[image]

How do i do that? I'm getting null when i refresh the preview

Comment: Is [currentUTC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#currentutc) what you are looking for?

Comment: I could use currentutc but if i use AEST as the param for the timezone, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to repro I see the same thing

[image]

As a workaround you can try few options as below

Use `currentUTC('AEST')`

[image]

**Note:** Data preview always shows in UTC. Check form the output dataset to be precise.

[image]

You can also use  `fromUTC(currentUTC(),'Antarctica/Macquarie')`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Refer this notation: worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

toString(currentUTC(),'yyyyMMdd','AEST')

This will work simply and you can change the format according to your need.